# query for last 10 items in dynamodb shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm learning Dynamodb and for that I installed the local server that comes with a shell at http://localhost:8000/shell

now.. I created the following table:

```
var serverUpTimeTableName = 'bingodrive_server_uptime';
var eventUpTimeColumn = 'up_time';

var params = {
    TableName: serverUpTimeTableName,
    KeySchema: [ // The type of of schema.  Must start with a HASH type, with an optional second RANGE.
        { // Required HASH type attribute
            AttributeName: eventUpTimeColumn,
            KeyType: 'HASH',
        },
    ],
   AttributeDefinitions: [ // The names and types of all primary and index key attributes only
        {
            AttributeName: eventUpTimeColumn,
            AttributeType: 'N', // (S | N | B) for string, number, binary
        },
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: { // required provisioned throughput for the table
        ReadCapacityUnits: 2,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 2,
    }
};
dynamodb.createTable(params, callback);
```

so I created a table only with one hash key called up_time, that's actually the only item in the table.

Now I want to fetch the last 10 inserted up times.

so far I created the following code:

```
var serverUpTimeTableName = 'bingodrive_server_uptime';

var eventUpTimeColumn = 'up_time';

var params = {
    TableName: serverUpTimeTableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: eventUpTimeColumn + ' != :value',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':value':0
    },
    Limit: 10,
    ScanIndexForward: false
}
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
else ppJson(data); // successful response

});
```

ok.. so few things to notice:

1. I don't really need a KeyCondition. i just want the last 10 items, so I used `Limit 10` for the limit and `ScanIndexForward:false` for reverse order.
2. `!=` or `NE` are not supported in key expressions for hash keys. and it seems that I must use some kind of index in the query.. confused about that.

so.. any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some modern terminology: Hash is now called Partition, Range is now called Sort. 

Thank you Amazon.

You need to understand that `Query`-ing is an action on hash-keys. In order to initiate a query you must supply a hash-key. Since your table's primary key is only hash key (and not hash+range) you **can't query** it. You can only `Scan` it in order to find items. Scan doesn't require any knowledge about items in the table.

Moving on.. when you say "last 10 items" you actually do want a condition because you are filtering on the date attribute, you haven't defined any index so you can't have the engine provide you 10 results. If it were a range key element, you could get the Top-10 ordered elements by querying with a backwards index (`ScanIndexForward:false`) - again, not your schema.

In your current table - what exactly are you trying to do? You currently only have one attribute which is also the hash key so 10 items would look like (No order, no duplicates):

```
12312
53453
34234
123
534534
3101
11
```

You could move those to range key and have a global hash-key "stub" just to initiate the query you're making but that breaks the guidelines of DynamoDB as you have a hot partition and it won't have the best performance. Not sure this bothers you at the moment, but it is worth mentioning.